# Intune script deployment failed

Tags: powershell, endpoint, intune

I am pushing a script to devices that downloads and executed exe installation, when checking on device, all is good and the app was pushed to uninstall specific application from the device.

```
    $url = "some url to *.zip"
$DownloadFile = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads" + $(Split-Path -Path $url -Leaf)
$ExtractPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $DownloadFile
$ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$ExtractFiles = $ExtractShell.Namespace($DownloadFile).Items()
$ExtractShell.Namespace($ExtractPath).CopyHere($ExtractFiles)
Start-Process $ExtractPath
Timeout /T 10
Start-Transcript
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\*.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru
```

So, the whole process is finished but in the Intune it shows as failed.

This is error log:

DNS detection: WinHttpGetProxyForUrl call failed because of error 12180
DHCP detection: WinHttpGetProxyForUrl call failed because of error 12180

For Intune script, there is no prerequisites for accessing specific link but I guess it is trying to access one: https://fef.msub03.manage.microsoft.com/TrafficGateway/TrafficRoutingService/SideCar/StatelessSideCarGatewayService

Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/managed-desktop/get-ready/network?view=o365-worldwide

Anyone had same issue, how to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, by bad guys, issue with the script.
Removed: Start-Process $ExtractPath
All is good now. Also, if anyone will need with implementation of try catch:

```
Write-Output "-------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Output "Starting script deployment for myapp"
Write-Output "-------------------------------------------------------------"
try {
    #Declare variables
    $url = "somelocation.file.zip" 
    $DownloadFile = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads" + $(Split-Path -Path $url -Leaf) 
    $ExtractPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads"
    #Removing possible broken file from previous push
    Remove-Item "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\myfile.exe"
    #Download and extract file
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $DownloadFile 
    $ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
    $ExtractFiles = $ExtractShell.Namespace($DownloadFile).Items() 
    $ExtractShell.Namespace($ExtractPath).CopyHere($ExtractFiles)
    timeout /T 5
    #Installation section of file
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\myfile.exe" -Argument '/S','/qn' -PassThru
}
catch {
    #If there are errors, catch them and display
    Write-Host "The error is:"`n -ForegroundColor Blue
    Write-Host "Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)"] -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor DarkBlue
}
```